# CSS- webkit-text-stroke but stroke covers font-color

Tags: css, webkit, stroke

Please take a look at here using Chrome : http://jsfiddle.net/u8BdB/

Why the `webkit-text-stroke` is covering also the font color?

I would like to put stroke outside of the text, it seems like it is assumed inside so it covers the font color :/ unbelievable

any help appriciated thanks.

Comment: If you make the text larger you will see the text color: http://jsfiddle.net/u8BdB/1/

Comment: @NaveTseva ok but so we can confirm that text-stroke only works for higer font-size which is bad :/

Comment: Now it's ok? http://jsfiddle.net/u8BdB/3/

Comment: @NaveTseva thanks a lot but it's a shit IMO i mean it really doesn't looks like a text stroke, it covers letters check deeply :/

Comment: checked you need font-weight bold to make it appear as much possible as a stroke :/  @NaveTseva

Comment: Check this, I think that this is the best you can get here: http://jsfiddle.net/u8BdB/5/

Comment: @NaveTseva ok gonna not use text-stroke uff but what a shitty property, it doesn't works as expected i'll wait until this property will be ok before to use it thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a CSS-based outside text stroke by using ::pseudo-elements. You can actually even do 2 layers of outside stroke.

You can see the technique on http://www.petercarrero.com/examples/stroke/

This method works only for web-kit browsers. The article also mentions a few of the caveats you need to be aware of to get good results.

I hope that helps you.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the font is relatively small comparing to the `1px` stroke.

You can try smaller px value, like `0.3px`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/478yS/)

Also you can simulate this with `text-shadow`:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/478yS/3/)

Comment: check if i want 3px stroke and bold text see what a shit lol http://jsfiddle.net/478yS/1/ unbelievable, unusefull property IMO @algiecas

Comment: Well, it looks better :) But to be honest, I don't know how the pixel can be smaller than 1 :)

Comment: i was gonna deleting my question, really , property is not well rendered IMO, i need to wait until it will be ok :/ thanks a lot anyway +1 for your answer

Comment: Added another example where you can simulate this with text-shadow property

Comment: yep thanks a lot i already got how to simulate that but it's not really good rendered too imo :P