# Add stroke around text - on the outside - with css?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML and CSS:

```css
body { background-color: gray; }
h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.5em;
}
```

```html
<h1>WHAT CARRER SHOULD YOU HAVE ?</h1>
```

Which renders like this:

[image]

I want to add a stroke around it, that means a black border around these text.
I Googled and found `-webkit-text-stroke`, and came up with:

```css
body { background-color: gray; }
h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px black;
}
```

```html
<h1>WHAT CARRER SHOULD YOU HAVE ?</h1>
```

However, the effect is not what I want:

[image]

As you can see, it seems that the stroke is added **inside** the text, which make the text looks too thin for me.

How can I make the stroke outside the text?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jpjbk1z7/

PS: only webkit support is needed

Comment: use text-shadow. Example : http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/jpjbk1z7/1/

Comment: I found this on google: "use the :before pseudo-element with the -webkit-text-stroke property set to create a "stroked" copy of the main text, then use z-index to put the copy behind the original, ending up with an outside stroke" http://www.petercarrero.com/examples/stroke/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS- webkit-text-stroke but stroke covers font-color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17484262/css-webkit-text-stroke-but-stroke-covers-font-color)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### The `-webkit-text-stroke` doesn't support placing the stroke on the outside of the text

as this [CSS-Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-stroke/) explains:

> The stroke drawn by text-stroke is aligned to the center of the text
> shape (as is the default in Adobe Illustrator), and there is currently
> no option to set the alignment to the inside or outside of the shape.
> Unfortunately this makes it much less usable, as no matter what now
> the stroke interferes with the shape of the letter destroying the
> original type designers intent. A setting would be ideal, but if we
> had to pick one, outside stroke would have been much more useful.

### What about SVG?

Well it seems that it also places the stroke on the inside -

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/danield770/zu51wgko/1/)**

### However,

you might be able to *simulate* this effect (depending on what you need) by:

1. Change your font to a sans serif like verdana  and
2. Increase the font-size of the text you are adding a stroke to.

```css
body {
  background: grey;
  font-family: verdana;
}
.stroke,
.no-stroke {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.5em;
}
.stroke {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px black;
   font-size: 2.7em;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="stroke">WHAT CAREER SHOULD YOU HAVE?</h1>
<h1 class="no-stroke">WHAT CAREER SHOULD YOU HAVE?</h1>
```

Comment: It is now possible to place the stroke outside the text with [paint-order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/paint-order)

Comment: @FelipeCortez shame it isn't supported in many browsers (e.g. Chrome) because `paint-order` would be really useful

Answer (score 58):

For a smooth outside stroke emulated by text shadow, use the following 8-axis shadow:

```
  text-shadow:
    -1px -1px 0 #000,
     0   -1px 0 #000,
     1px -1px 0 #000,
     1px  0   0 #000,
     1px  1px 0 #000,
     0    1px 0 #000,
    -1px  1px 0 #000,
    -1px  0   0 #000;
```

For customisation, you can use this SASS mixin instead (although changing the size does have side effects on rendering):

```
@mixin stroke($color: #000, $size: 1px) {
  text-shadow:
    -#{$size} -#{$size} 0 $color,
     0        -#{$size} 0 $color,
     #{$size} -#{$size} 0 $color,
     #{$size}  0        0 $color,
     #{$size}  #{$size} 0 $color,
     0         #{$size} 0 $color,
    -#{$size}  #{$size} 0 $color,
    -#{$size}  0        0 $color;
}
```

This gives a very smooth stroke, without missing parts, like on the 4 axis solution.

Comment: Very cool and simple. The only thing is, I can't understand why it appears to have a slightly thicker stroke on the top than the bottom. Until I zoom in, then it looks correct.

Comment: Thank you, Ryall ! Your 8-Axis "outline" rescued me when trying to emulate an outline around a subtitle text. I had tried canvas, but then found that doesn't support underlines. Using JS - with variables used to replace the user selected pixel widths - have solved the software conundrum in a couple of hours.

Comment: Thanks but what if instead of "#{$" use "var(...)"? Rendering will suffer either way?

Comment: It only works with 1px. Any other value will yield an unpleasant result

Comment: S's fail to render properly because of their shape. This solution is fine, but doesn't work as well as you'd hope.

Answer (score 54):

Firefox and Safari now support a new CSS property called [`paint-order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/paint-order) which [can be used to simulate an outside stroke](https://css-tricks.com/text-stroke-stuck-middle/#article-header-id-2):

```css
h1 {
  color: #00ff01;
  font-size: 3em;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 5px black;
}

.fix-stroke {
   paint-order: stroke fill;
}
```

```html
<h1>the default often is ugly</h1>
<h1 class="fix-stroke">paint-order: stroke fill </h1>
```

## Screenshot:

[image: CSS paint-order screenshot]

Comment: Will be great if this gets added to Chrome also!

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it still doesn't work in Chrome :(

Comment: @mmaismma Thanks for the edit but the support table on caniuse.com is about `paint-order` support on SVG `<text>` elements. Unfortunately Google Chrome still doesn't support `paint-order` on HTML elements.

Comment: As of Chrome 84 (July 13, 2020) - Chrome now supports paint-order.  https://caniuse.com/#search=paint-order

Comment: @RockyKev No, unfortunately it does not. See my comment above. (Or just click the "Run code snippet" button above using Chrome)

Comment: It's a shame that Chrome *still* doesn't support it for standard `HTMLElements`. [MDN Has demos of it that work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/paint-order), but it only works on SVG elements, like: `<svg><text>Demo</text></svg>`

Comment: Now in 2023 and Chrome *still* doesn’t support paint-order for HTML elements.

Comment: Chrome now supports paint-order from version `123 (Released 2024-03-19)`.

Comment: Opera has limited support on this: https://caniuse.com/?search=paint-order

Answer (score 25):

One option is to use `text-shadow` to simulate a stroke. Example:

```
text-shadow:
    -1px -1px 0 #000,  
     1px -1px 0 #000,
    -1px  1px 0 #000,
     1px  1px 0 #000;
```

Comment: this is as good a cross-browser solution as you will get... unfortunately, with thicker borders, this looks strange on serif fonts.

Comment: For a smoother version, use 8 axis instead of 4. See my answer for the code.

Answer (score 13):

Further elaborating on the other `text-shadow` solutions, for pixel-perfect **thick round outlines** the number of shadows should increase with the radius of the stroke. For example, a 10px thick outline requires 2⋅10⋅π ≈ 63 shadows distributed in all directions. To generate this in javascript, one could something like:

```js
  const color = "#FFF" /* white outline */
  const r = 10 /* width of outline in pixels */
  const n = Math.ceil(2*Math.PI*r) /* number of shadows */
  var str = ''
  for(var i = 0;i<n;i++) /* append shadows in n evenly distributed directions */
  {
    const theta = 2*Math.PI*i/n
    str += (r*Math.cos(theta))+"px "+(r*Math.sin(theta))+"px 0 "+color+(i==n-1?"":",")
  }
  document.querySelector("#myoutlinedtext").style.textShadow = str
```

[image: example of thick outlined text]

If the thickness is static, then just run this once to generate the string and paste it into your CSS.

Comment: I wrote a SCSS mixin to achieve a similar effect: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72876332/4414003

Comment: I made a simple function that uses the same method that is called by className see: (https://gist.github.com/Langerz82/d3284e1ba2192699e438a9ae87974bf6)

Answer (score 5):

One way I found was to stack two elements on each other having the element that stays behind get the **double** stroke width. The element behind leaks the stroke to the outside of the visible element making it a true stroke outside.

Also, another option is to use `:after` to create this second element. The downside is that you can't programmatically change the stroke

This might not work properly on big stroke values.

```css
body { background-color: gray; }
h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-family: verdana;
}

.stroke { -webkit-text-stroke: 2px black; }

.stack .stroke { -webkit-text-stroke: 4px black; }
h1.stroke-fs { font-size: 2.7em; }

.stack { position: relative; }
.stack > h1:not(:first-child) {
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}


.stroke-after:after { 
  -webkit-text-stroke: 4px black;
  content: attr(value);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
Stack
<div class="stack">
  <h1 class="stroke">WHAT CARRER SHOULD YOU HAVE ?</h1>
  <h1>WHAT CARRER SHOULD YOU HAVE ?</h1>
</div>

<hr />

After
<div style="position: relative">
  <h1 class="stroke-after" value="WHAT CARRER SHOULD YOU HAVE ?">WHAT CARRER SHOULD YOU HAVE ?</h1>
</div>

<hr />

Native
<h1 class="stroke">WHAT CARRER SHOULD YOU HAVE ?</h1>

<hr />

Font size
<h1 class="stroke stroke-fs">WHAT CARRER SHOULD YOU HAVE ?</h1>
```

Comment: Also found a post on `:before` and `:after` https://www.petercarrero.com/examples/stroke/

Answer (score 1):

I have also tried text-shadow and -webkit-text-stroke, but unsuccessful in all ways.
I could only get the result by making two divs(background and foreground) i.e,

background div with -webkit-text-stroke and foreground div without -webkit-text-stroke.

```
<div style="position:absolute;width:1280px;height:720px;left:0px;top:0px" >
    <div style="color:#CDCDCD;
                font-family:sans-serif;
                font-size:57px;
                -webkit-text-stroke-color:black;
                -webkit-text-stroke-width:0.04em;" >
        <p>
            Text with outine stroke outwards.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="position:absolute;width:1280px;height:720px;left:0px;top:0px" >
    <div style="color:#CDCDCD;
                font-family:sans-serif;
                font-size:57px;" >
        <p>
            Text with outine stroke outwards.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Bt the only problem with the html generated through is twice the size(size in memory) as the div is repeated twice.

Does anyone has some better solution?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but have a look at this:

https://jsfiddle.net/1dbta9cq/

you can simply place another text on top of the stroked text with absolute positioning, it's not so tidy but it solves the problem

```
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="stroke">Stroke</h1>
  <h1 class="no-stroke">Stroke</h1>
</div>

.container{
  width:300px;
}

.stroke{
  position:absolute;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 10px black;
}

.no-stroke{
  color:white;
  position:absolute
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a SCSS mixin for simulating text outlines with multiple shadows:

```scss
@use "sass:math";
@use 'sass:list';

@mixin text-outline($offset, $color, $num-steps: 16) {
  $shadows: ();
  @for $i from 0 to $num-steps {
    $angle: $i * 360deg / $num-steps;
    $x: calc(#{math.cos($angle)} * #{$offset});
    $y: calc(#{math.sin($angle)} * #{$offset});
    $shadows: list.append($shadows, #{$x} #{$y} 0 #{$color}, $separator: comma);
  }
  text-shadow: $shadows;
}
```

For larger offsets, a greater number of shadows (“steps”) is required for good results. Note that in general, however, more shadows will be more expensive for the browser to render.

Example:

```scss
span {
  color: #FF004D;
  @include utils.type-outline(
    $offset: calc(0.05rem + 0.05em),
    $color: #FFFFFF,
    $num-steps: 32
  );
}
```

Result:
[image: white outline around text]

Answer (score 0):

Text shadow might be used to achieve this result
http://css3generator.com

Comment: With `text-shadow` you can just get some blurred shadow and the best you can get for border solid with this is just 1px ... I don't think the OP wants that. Also avoid just link answer include some code an example to get upvotes :)

Comment: Not really a fair comment, especially considering the correct answer and its improvement. However, the answer still doesn't support an upvote. The broken link, for one thing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a SASS mixin I created to make it easy to create a text outline using the prefixed properties (`-webkit`, `-moz`) when supported, but falling back to just a color with text shadow.  Note that the fallback doesn't work well with opaque fill colors, but other than that I think it's a pretty good solution, until we can get a standard method that has better browser support.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3yzxq41g/4/)

**Mixin**

```
@mixin text-stroke($fill-color, $stroke-color, $stroke-width) {
  color: $fill-color;
  text-shadow: -$stroke-width -$stroke-width 0 $stroke-color,
                $stroke-width -$stroke-width 0 $stroke-color,
               -$stroke-width  $stroke-width 0 $stroke-color,
                $stroke-width  $stroke-width 0 $stroke-color;

  @supports ((-webkit-text-stroke-color: $stroke-color) and (-webkit-text-fill-color: white))
            or ((-moz-text-stroke-color: $stroke-color) and (-moz-text-fill-color: white)) {
                        color: unset;
                  text-shadow: unset;
         -moz-text-fill-color: $fill-color;
      -webkit-text-fill-color: $fill-color;
       -moz-text-stroke-color: $stroke-color;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: $stroke-color;
       -moz-text-stroke-width: $stroke-width;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: $stroke-width;
  }
}
```

**Example Usage**

(Makes text semi-transparent black with a white outline)

```
.heading-outline {
  @include text-stroke(rgba(#000,.5), #fff, 1px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom attribute which is the same as the node's text content, and define a pseudo-class `::before` which acts as the non-stroked text, which will be rendered in front of the stroked text, creating the desired illusion of a text being stroked on the outside only:

```css
label {
  user-select: none;
}

label:has(:checked) ~ .stroke::before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none; /* for text selection */
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0px;
}

.stroke {
  margin: .5em;
  font: 60px arial;
  
  /* trick */
  position: relative;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 20px purple;
  color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type=checkbox checked> With trick
</label>
<h1 class="stroke" data-text="Nice little trick">Nice little trick</h1>
```

In the future, when Chrome solves this, you could simply delete the `::before` selector.

---

I've opened a request in the CSS community to improve the `content` property: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/8894

Answer (score 0):

**html**:

```html
<div class="text-stroke" data-text="Your text">Your text</div>
```

**css**:

```css
.text-stroke {
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    
    &:after {
        content: attr(data-text);
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        -webkit-text-stroke: 2px #000;
        -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
        z-index: -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I like this solution, great use of css multi layer and `attr` function!

Answer (score -1):

I'm obviously late to the party but I find the easiest is probably the best way forward to a solution.

For me, I did the outside stroke effect by just making the weight of the font larger.

```
body { background-color: gray; }
h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px black;
}
```

Is it the most correct ?

Depending on the situation then the answer is yes Or no.

Does it work in your use case ?
 ...for me , yes perfefctly.