# Controling the type of stroke (-webkit-text-stroke)

Tags: html, css, stroke

I am trying to replicate a design element and remove the image and hopefully replace it with plain HTML/CSS. Essentially I have a ***header > h1*** that has a title in it. For example we'll say this title is "Stack Overflow", like so..

```
<header>
  <h1>
    Stack Overflow
  </h1>
</header>
```

In my current CSS, the text-indent is pushed off the screen and a background is applied to the ***h1***.

To replace that I'm using the ***-webkit-text-stroke:***   rule which works fine, albeit not being fully supported across all browsers. The problem with it is one that many Photoshop users come across when applying stroke to text and that is the position of stroke.

Let me demonstrate with a badly put together image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucFBm.jpg - the top text shows stroke that is "outside" of the text, the bottom one uses what Photoshop calls "center".

It seems that ***-webkit-text-stroke*** based it's stroke on that "center" variant in Photoshop. I'd very much like it to replicate the "outside" option.

I can't see anywhere I can set this, and I'm guessing I can't but I'd be interested to know if..

a) there is a method, and if so what is it?
b) if there isn't a method, has anyone found a different way of achieving this?

Now I should say, I found this: [https://www.petercarrero.com/examples/stroke](https://www.petercarrero.com/examples/stroke/) which in turn came from a post posted on here in 2013 ([CSS- webkit-text-stroke but stroke covers font-color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17484262/css-webkit-text-stroke-but-stroke-covers-font-color))

On caveat here is that I believe SVG can control the stroke type and I would be interested to see any solutions that use it, but ideally I am not targetting an SVG solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A) `text-stroke` is not part of the CSS standard and thus the implementation might differ from browser to browser or is missing at all. B) You can find some other workarounds of combined CSS techniques over [at CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/adding-stroke-to-web-text/); C) It could probably be a solution to use a font family that is an outline font and apply an inner shadow to it to achieve a similar result; e.g. https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/tag/outline

Comment: a) I mentioned in my post it wasn't fully supported across all browsers. it's still covered by quite a lot.

b) checked places like css tricks already (and a few other places)

c) I need to use a specific font, hence why I used an image before hand.

Ultimately if there is no easy solution, I'm fine with that.

Comment: Ah option D) use SVG to render the font and the stroke; but I guess that would require some deep dives into SVG font rendering.

Comment: Yeah. I think it's doable in svg as it has specific stroke settings. Just wondered if there was a way without using it. That said, it's just plain text so theoretically SVG shouldn't be overly complicated (heh, I presume! I rarely touch svg)

Comment: Using this logic, JavaScript is also plain text and shouldn't be overly complicated to learn. Don't fool yourself into weeks of work.

Comment: Don't really agree with the analogy to be fair as I believe importing fonts to SVG is not a complicated task. That said, the message of "don't go into a technology assuming it's simple" is definitely a fair comment.